# Tighten loose upholstery button

Tags: furniture

I have an upholstery button on the armrest a sofa that is loose.

[image: loose button]

How can I tighten this?

Edit: I do have access to basic sewing materials and tools.

Comment: Can you access the underside or inside of the armrest/cushion/whatever part of sofa this is?

Comment: @Stephie let me check when I get home...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, cut the button off the string, making sure the string stays in position as it is now.

Next, have a 2nd person compress the cushion as far as practicable and hold it in this position.  Re-tie the button to the strings as close to the cushion as desired (possible?), leaving the excess thread hanging.

Cut off the excess, leaving enough to ensure that the knot will not untie itself, and release the pressure on the cushion.